# how to transform in python a variable in to array?

Tags: python, arrays

i have a STRING VARIABLE like this:

```
x = "[str1, str2]"
```

look, variable x IS NOT an array

when i do:

```
print x
>>> [str1, str2]
```

there is a direct way to transform variable "x" from a string variable into an array? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `str1` and `str2` are not valid python expressions. No valid `list` can be created from this.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist, you can do

```
x = eval("['a', 'b']")
```

However make sure to read on security issues with using `eval`

A better solution would be to understand the format of your data and use a parser to get the data you want

Comment: You should  keep in mind, that `eval()` has the risk of code execution if the evaluated expression comes from a third party.

Comment: That will only work if `str1` and `str2` are in the namespace.

Comment: Agreed this is no way to build a program